# how to use flask render_template API to return multiple images for a HTML template in the template folder?

Tags: python, flask

I want to read some local images(.jpg) from a local file path, then display those images on a web page(127.0.0.1:8000) by using flask and python3.I have already display single image on web page by use the following code:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
 
app = Flask(__name__)
 
 
def return_img_stream(img_local_path):
    import base64
    img_stream = ''
    with open(img_local_path, 'rb') as img_f:
        img_stream = img_f.read()
        img_stream = base64.b64encode(img_stream).decode()
    return img_stream
 
 
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    img_path = 'D:\\1111\\1.jpg'
    img_stream = return_img_stream(img_path)

    return render_template('index.html',img_stream=img_stream)
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,host='127.0.0.1',port=8080)
```

How should I modify return_img_stream and hello_world function to use flask read multi images stream and send it to 'index.html' template?

Comment: if you would have images in folder `static` then you could send only list with filenames and use `for`-loop in template to generate like `<img src="/static/1.jpg">`

Comment: you will have to use `for`-loop in `hello_world` to create list with many `img_stream` - and later you will need `for`-loop in template to display it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

If you would have images in folder `static` then you could send only list with filenames and use `for`-loop in template to generate tags like `<img src="/static/1.jpg">`

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    #filenames = os.listdir('static')
    filenames = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg'] 

    return render_template('index.html', filenames=filenames)
```

template

```
{% for name in filenames %}
  <img src="/static/{{ name }}">
{% endfor %}
```

---

If you need to use `base64` then you have to use `for`-loop in Flask

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    #filenames = os.listdir('D:\\1111')
    #filenames = [os.path.join('D:\\1111', name) for name in filenames]
    filenames = ['D:\\1111\\1.jpg', 'D:\\1111\\2.jpg']

    images = []

    for img_path in filenames:
        img_stream = return_img_stream(img_path)
        images.append(img_stream)

    return render_template('index.html', images=images)
```

template

```
{% for img in images %}
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, {{ img }}">
{% endfor %}
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you would merge all images to create single image then you would need modules like `pillow` or `opencv` to convert `jpg` to raw image, merge them, convert it back to single `jpg`.

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to add images with some text (ie. with filename) then you have to create list with pairs `(image, text)` and `{% for img, txt in images %}` and put text using `{{ txt }}`

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    #filenames = os.listdir('D:\\1111')
    #filenames = [os.path.join('D:\\1111', name) for name in filenames]
    filenames = ['D:\\1111\\1.jpg', 'D:\\1111\\2.jpg']

    images = []

    for img_path in filenames:
        img_stream = return_img_stream(img_path)
        images.append( [img_stream, img_path ])

    return render_template('index.html', images=images)
```

template

```
{% for img, txt in images %}
  filename: {{ txt }}<br/>
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, {{ img }}">
{% endfor %}
```

---

But if you mean `text on image` then it may need [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to edit images and put text on images.
Or you will have to learn `CSS` for positioning elements in `HTML`.

```
<style>
  div.image { ... }
  div.image span { ... }
</style>

{% for img, txt in images %}
  <div class="image">
     <span>filename: {{ txt }}</span>
     <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, {{ img }}">
  <div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you! My images are not in static folder,because I want to use this code show different images on a web page.If I want to show some text at the top of each image on the web page,how should I modify the index.html?

Comment: if you want to put text in HTML then create list with pairs `images = [(image, text), ...]` and use `{% for img, text in images %}` and simply put it as `{{ txt }}`. But if you mean `text on image` then may need to use module `pillow` to edit image - or you will have to learn `CSS` to positioning elements in HTML.

Comment: I added some code with `(image, text)` in answer.

Comment: hi,you code is very helpful! I‘m a newbie for flask and html,I want to use CSS to setting my images and text attributes,but i don't know how.I want to arrange multiple images in line-first order, and when one line is full, they will be sorted to the next line. Each image is scaled to the absolute width and height，and the original aspect ratio of the picture is not maintained. There is a text at the top of the image, and the font size can be set for the text (the text is not in the image).

Comment: you would have to find some tutorial - like [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/). Eventually you could use some `CSS Framework` - like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/images/), [UIKit](https://getuikit.com/docs/overlay) - to use only classes to assign some CSS settings. ie. [14 Best CSS Frameworks for Front-End Developers](https://geekflare.com/best-css-frameworks/)

Comment: One more question,if I want to take the img_path variable as the parameter of hello_world function,how to pass this parameter to the hello_world function when executing app.run()？

Comment: do you mean to get from command line when you start script? Before `app.run()` you would need to get it from `sys.argv` and assign to global variable i.e `path = sys.argv[1]` and `hello_world` would have to use this value directly from global variable `path`. You can't run it as `hello_world(path)`because it doesn't work this way. `app.run()` control when to execute `hello_world()` and send result to browser - and it do it only when it get request from browser. If you would run directly `hello_world(path)` then it would send response to console but it wouldn't send `path` to browser

Comment: yes,I have already solve this question.And I use the same solution as your said.Thanks any way!